# Inversion Formula in Conformal Field Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

I was working on my thesis on Conformal Bootstraps. For that, I now have to use the [inversion formula](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=inversion&as_epq=conformal+field+theory) to get anomalous dimensions in the $\phi^3$ theory.
Can anyone suggest any good reference(s) to learn how to use Inversion Formula in CFT?

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are already familiar with the reviews of conformal bootstrap, but this is the standard list

1. David Simmons Duffin's TASI lectures [1602.07982](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982)
2. Slava Rychkov's EPFL lectures [1601.05000](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000)
3. Recent numerical bootstrap review [1805.04405](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04405)

These links *don't* discuss the inversion formula (except sec IX of 3. very briefly), but the notations and all basic facts about CFTs are in there, so it's important to at least have them in mind. Now for the inversion formula papers:

4. Original paper by Caron Huot [1703.00278](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00278)
5. Formal proof by Witten Stanford and Simmons Duffin [1711.03816](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03816)
6. Version in Mellin space [1803.05086](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05086)
7. Generalization to arbitrary spin [1805.00098](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00098)
8. Explicit results for OPE coefficients in Mean Free Theory [1809.05111](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05111)

A similar story was developed for CFTs at finite temperature

9. Seminal paper [1802.10266](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10266)
10. Application to Ising [1811.05451](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05451)

The inversion formula can be applied to the $1/J$ perturbation theory, a.k.a. "Lightcone bootstrap" or "Analytic bootstrap". This subject was developed before the formula had been discovered, so in these papers there is a different language.

11. Seminal (independent) papers [1212.4103](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4103), [1212.3616](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3616)
12. Application to 3d Ising [1612.08471](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08471)
13. Many other refs. for which I refer you to the intro of 7.
14. Wilson Fisher with lightcone bootstrap [1712.02314](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02314)

I emphasize the last one because you will probably need similar techniques if you are studying this $\phi^3$ theory with a sort of $\varepsilon$ expansion.